# How to get the source code of a website using angularjs?

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

I'm trying to get the content of my angularjs website, include html and css.
This code is get html only, I want to get all css, and it is external style sheet.

```
     .downloadAsFile = function(filename, type, data) {
        window.URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
        var a = document.createElement("a");
        var blob = new Blob([data], {type: type});
        var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        document.body.appendChild(a);
        a.href = url;
        a.download = filename;
        a.click();
        window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
        document.body.removeChild(a);
    };

    .exportHTML = function(){
        var Data = document.getElementById("widget-grid").innerHTML;
        self.downloadAsFile('file.html', 'text/html', Data);
    };
```

And "widget-grid" element has many child elements.

Thanks.

Comment: you just need to read the html file and follow every link, href, src, link ...

Comment: but I want to download a html file and it has css style in it. It is a function for 'end user'.

Comment: And... you still need to follow every link, href, src, link. You will likely have problems with CORS at this point, so the question is XY problem.